# How to implement InputCheckbox OnChange Event?

Tags: c#, blazor, editform

I have a InputCheckbox in an EditForm. This is used in a Blazor Web Server application. I want to show and hide a text field based on the check box state. I am unable to get the event for ValueChanged to work correctly.

```
<EditForm id="formMember" Model="@member">
<InputCheckbox 
   id="Adegree12" 
   class="form-check-input" 
   Value="member.Adegree12" 
   ValueChanged="((bool Adegree) => ADegreeSelectionChanged(Adegree))" 
   ValueExpression="(() => member.Adegree12)" />
</EditForm>
```

I am using this code for the InputCheckbox. Without the "Value" attribute the functionality works fine. I can catch the changed value and show or hide the text field. But when I added the "Value" attribute, the checkbox stopped changing. I have added the "Value" attribute to use the same form for the Edit scenario.

Update: If I remove the Editform tag then the functionality works fine. But with the Editform tag, if the checkbox is clicked then it checks and unchecks instantly which wrong. Maybe I am not using the EditForm tag correctly?

Comment: Syntax should look like this: `<InputCheckbox ValueChanged="@((e) => CheckboxChanged(e))">` Maybe you forgot the `@`

Comment: Note, that you cannot use `@bind-Value` and `ValueChanged` together. That's why `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression` are required to achieve similar behaviour.

Comment: `@` doesn't make any difference as ValueChanged is a Razor component attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code I can't answer based on your context.  Instead I've constructed a simple `Index` to demonstrate how the binding works in principle.  Note both types of binding work.

The simpler second version works because the compiled Razor code looks similar to the first example.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <InputCheckbox class="form-check" Value="_hide1" ValueChanged="CheckBoxChanged" ValueExpression="() => _hide1" />
        <InputText hidden="@_hide1" class="form-control mb-3" @bind-Value="@_textValue1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <InputCheckbox class="form-check" @bind-Value="_hide2" />
        <InputText hidden="@_hide2" class="form-control mb-3" @bind-Value="@_textValue2" />
    </div>
</div>


@code{
    private string? _textValue1;
    private string? _textValue2;
    private bool _hide1;
    private bool _hide2;

    private void CheckBoxChanged(bool state)
    {
        _hide1 = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped me further pin point the issue. I have updated my original question. The issue now seams to be with the EditForm tag.

Comment: I have checked my code again. The real reason was that I was not assigned the changed value to the bind value in the change event function.

```private void CheckBoxChanged(bool state) {
        _hide1 = state;
}```

Thank you for providing me with the code sample. It was a simple thing that I was missing.